# how to get Temporary access key and secret key from the role based ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a role based ec2 instance(lynx) with me I need the temporary access key and secrete key from the meta-data how can I get it?

I have tried with this url curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-keys but its not giving me anything

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [AWS STS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html). You haven't defined your language so I can only give you a general approach.

1. Assign your roles access and private key to the `STS Client`
2. Call the API function `getSessionToken`
3. In the response you receive the temporary credentials.

By default these tokens are valid for 24 hours, this can of course be changed. Simple read the manual about AWS STS and you should be able to configure it to your liking.

I hope you find this answer helpful and useful.